# Storing email addresses in plain text is okay?

Tags: encryption, databases, data-leakage, storage

You know one of those news when someone says "thousands of users' passwords and personal emails have leaked...". It's the type of stuff that I assume would be prevented if the emails were encrypted in the app's logic, before storing them into the database, because whoever gets the database dump, doesn't necessarily have the decryption key.

Yet, I cannot find any such advice when I search how to store emails in a database. And anything that revolves around question about storing emails, is usually about length and charsets, and everyone keeps implying that storing email addresses in plain text is okay.

It seems a little contradicting...

Should I encrypt email addresses before storing into the database? Would I gain anything by doing so? And do security-aware developers/companies usually do anything of that sort?

Comment: Your proposed solution assumes the attacker only gets access to the database. This does happen (see for example the number of NoSQL databases left open to the internet), but in many cases an attacker gets access through the web application itself. At that point, you have likely got access to any encryption keys that are required.

Comment: encrypting them might provide some protection from certain attacks... like an injection attack that outputs a whole database.  Or if the database is on a separate server.  Couldn't hurt...

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays with all the related data privacy regulations in place where it mandates protection data on transport and data on rest.

Hence you should encrypt those email address, which is considered as PII, when storing to database. Now this comes another level complexity since you need to protect your key that will be used for encrypting/decrypting.

What will you get? Well a solution that is partly compliant to data privacy regulations. This will add value to your solution especially if you are working or with a partnership with big companies (they have huge risk in case data breach will occur in terms of reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Encryption is a nice tool on an end user device, but is almost useless on a server. You (a live human being) are present when you boot your machine, and can give it all the passwords and keys that are necessary to unlock crypted disks or files. And you machine is normally off when you no longer use it, so it makes sense to protect data *at rest*.

When it comes to a server machine in a large datacenter, it runs unattended, and has to be able to reboot without any human action. This is just a consequence of the ratio number_of_servers / number_of_operators in the datacenter. So that means that if encryption is used anywhere but for dumb encrypted containers (*), the key shall be accessible on the machine itself, somewhat changing the encryption in mere obfuscation.

That is the reason why e-mail addresses are generally stored in plain text on the server databases, and why user passwords are not encrypted, but only non reversible hashes of them are kept on the server. At first sight, only offline storage (mainly backups) deserves encryption in a datacenter. Of course there are exceptions but they are *exceptional*.

---

(*) I call here *dumb encrypted container*, files that cannot be decrypted by the server but require a key that is only known to a remote client. This is commonly used for encrypted remote backups.

Answer (score 0):

If by "database" you mean a public github repo, then yes, you should encrypt any PII you put there (but for preference don't put it there).

But the best practice is to ensure that data is **protected** from accidental disclosure. Encryption is one of many tools to do that. Which tools are appropriate depends on where the database is, who has access to it, where the backups go and who has access to them. There are a lot of ways to encrypt data and each method has a lot of different implications for functionality, availability, performance and capacity.

Since we know nothing about what how protected or exposed your data might be, it is impossible to advise whether you should consider or avoid encryption.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how your organization considers email addresses. Encryption is the step of encrypting the data yet does the organization evaluated the system's operational overhead due to encryption and it's importance? Because encryption slightly increases your execution time and can hurt large business industries/organizations. With that, you must think of all aspects and consider solutions that can be accepted both by the organization and security team.

As per my recommendation, you should mask or obfuscate the email addresses that are stored in the database. Segregate the access controls and provide only need-to-know basis access to the front-end users. This not only will help you control the exposure of email addresses to database administrator but also will help you to maintain privacy policies (If considered by organization as per regulation or law) and prevent data exposures in future too.